# linking external library in IAR MSP430

Tags: embedded, linkage, msp430, iar

I created an MSP430 library file, and I want to link with it, but I don't find where I can add the libraries to link against in IAR gui.
Does anyone knows where to configure it ?

I've checked the documentation, but nothing appears to be related to external libraries, only the CLIB and DLIB.

Comment: Page 33 of the user manual says that you create projects which can contain source files or a library. Not clear but it is mentioned. It also describes how to do it in Tutorial 6 "Creating and using libraries".

Comment: @tinman the question you mentioned talks about linking a library which wasn't created with IAR compiler

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unlike other `IAR embedded workbench` releases (such as `IAR EWARM`), in `MSP430` you need to add the library you want to link against like you add a normal source/header file. 
This is a bit weird approach, but that how it's done.